# Does an ally count as a path?

Tags: call-to-adventure

With Redemption Seeker, whenever you attempt a triumph or radiance path, you gain a virtue. If an ally like Sister or True Love, which have triumph in their header, is on a challenge, would you gain virtue even if the path didn't have triumph listed in it originally? And if you do would you gain two virtue if the path has triumph in it?

Similarly, for Reluctant Villain, if you add an ally with triumph, does that count as adding a triumph path to your story for the purposes of receiving a hero card? If so, if it was a path with triumph originally, do you gain two hero cards then?